# Running Community detection and visualising Output in VisNetwork

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph, graph-visualization

I am trying to run betweeness and closeness centrality using VISNETWORK package in R.
The nodes are computed for the degree and visualized using below code. Does anyone has idea of how can I compute the other centrality measures and plot using the Visnetwork.

Attaching the code below to compute degree and sample dataset on which i am trying to compute other centrality measures.

```
graph <- graph.data.frame(retweeter_poster, directed=T)  ##retweeter_poster  who_retweet and who_post twitter network
graph <- simplify(graph)
V(graph)$indegree <- centr_degree(graph, mode = "in")$res
nodes <- get.data.frame(graph, what="vertices")
nodes <- data.frame(id = nodes$name, title = nodes$name, group = nodes$indegree, indegree = nodes$indegree)
setnames(nodes, "indegree", "in-degree centrality")
nodes <- nodes[order(nodes$id, decreasing = F),]
edges <- get.data.frame(graph, what="edges")[1:2]
visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "500px", width = "100%") %>%
visOptions(selectedBy = "in-degree centrality", highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE)%>%
visPhysics(stabilization = FALSE)


Source     Target
futatun2228 nanauehara0812
    Weltregierung   jounger
    soccelovexxxxx  evian_moe
    berlinerzeitung 13susang75
    ot113   evian_arswest
    ot113   evian_arswest
    berlinerzeitung Letnapark
    ot113   evian_arswest
    sternde xXNero03
    mkdirecto   Ms_Kowalsky
    ot113   evian_arswest
    p90tr2  evian_9
    sternde MARKENCHECKS
    ot113   evian_arswest
    ot113   evian_arswest
    shoko_ayu_1008  evian_arswest
    meikelobo   Andreas__Nagel
    mkdirecto   markiteando
    mkdirecto   nilsonliscano
    FlippinAlbanian LChanio
    sternde WWinfos
    HIFIMANJAPAN    evian
    berlinerzeitung daniel_makuch
    faznet  JrgenNaeve
    berlinerzeitung BerlinerNYC
    suarezphoto cebenna
    SPIEGELONLINE   Pahn2304Norbert
    SPIEGEL_Top Kawajoerg
    Klaus_Mueller   Rechtalltaglich
    an_evian @an_evian  Emiliya1207
    MDRaktuell  MARKANTdjPOOL
    salzburg_com    PeterHeinzl
    faznet  ingouschner
    derStandardat   Liese_Mueller
    faznet  RhydanR
    Klaus_Mueller   KolbaPeter
    SPIEGELONLINE   OneStepBayond
    Klaus_Mueller   VanessFred
    SPIEGELONLINE   frankschroedter
    SPIEGELONLINE   bolounitlne
    faznet  Rudini48
    berlinerzeitung Marina_Ilona
    jzaaaa80    evian_812
    HasnainKazim    OneStepBayond
    SPIEGELONLINE   OneStepBayond
    faznet  JcM_mr
    SPIEGELONLINE   HasnainKazim
    makaronn1gou    evian_arswest
    SPIEGELONLINE   askourgias
    SPIEGELONLINE   CausesPetitions
    faznet  Nur_mal_so1
    faznet  Ghostdogcs
```